# Error datatable mensaje cargando

Tags: php, javascript

Buenas devs tengo un pequeño problema, cuando mi datatable está vacío muestra un mensaje que dice ¨Cargando...¨ cuando en realidad debería mostrar el mensaje de ¨Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla¨, todo prosigue normal cuando ya tengo datos pero cuando los elimino y no queda ni uno sale ese mensaje ayúdenme por favor estoy usando codeigniter.
Si conocen alguna solución por favor ayúdenme con su conocimiento que lo valoro mucho.

**Este es mi Datatable**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tablaServicioTecnico').DataTable({
        
        'ajax': "http://localhost/ci3/ordenes_trabajo/servicio_tecnico/mostrar",
        dom: '<"datatable-header"fl><"datatable-scroll-wrap"t><"datatable-footer"ip>',
        order: [],
        responsive: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        processing: true,
        language: {
            "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
            "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sUrl": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            },
            // Select2 for length menu styling
            
            // Initialize
            
            search: '<span>Filtro:</span> _INPUT_',
            searchPlaceholder: 'Escriba para buscar...',
            lengthMenu: '<span>Mostrar:</span> _MENU_',
            paginate: {
                'first': 'First',
                'last': 'Last',
                'next': $('html').attr('dir') == 'rtl' ? '&larr;' : '&rarr;',
                'previous': $('html').attr('dir') == 'rtl' ? '&rarr;' : '&larr;'
            }
        },
        
    })
    $('.dataTables_length select').select2({
        minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
        dropdownAutoWidth: true,
        width: 'auto'
    });
})
```

**Aquí ¨dibujo¨ el datatable con los datos de la base de datos**

```
public function mostrar() {
            
            $resultadoList = $this->servicio_tecnico_model->mostrar();
            $resultado = array();
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($resultadoList as $key => $value) {
                $nombreApellido = $value['Nombre_Cliente'] . ' ' . $value['Apellido_Cliente'];
                $acciones = '<div class="list-icons"><a href="#" id="verOtServicioTecnico" value="' .
                    $value['ID_OTServicioTecnico'] . '" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon" type="button"><i class="icon-info22"></i></a><a href="#" id="editarOtServicioTecnico" value="' .
                    $value['ID_OTServicioTecnico'] . '" class="btn btn-warning btn-icon" type="button"><i class="icon-pencil7"></i></a><a href="#" id="eliminarOtServicioTecnico" value="' .
                    $value['ID_OTServicioTecnico'] . '"  class="btn btn-danger btn-icon" type="button"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></div>';
                
                $resultado['data'][] = array(
                    $i++,
                    $nombreApellido,
                    $value['Nombre_Documento'],
                    $value['NumeroDocumento_OTServicioTecnico'],
                    $value['Descripcion_OTServicioTecnico'],
                    $value['Fecha_OTServicioTecnico'],
                    $value['Total_OTServicioTecnico'],
                    $acciones
                );
            }
            echo json_encode($resultado);
            
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo conseguí solucionar agregando una condición si esque lo que viene de la base de datos no está vacío pues que se dibuje el datatable, sino que muestre un array vacío.

```
public function mostrar() {
            
            $resultadoList = $this->servicio_tecnico_model->mostrar();
            $resultado = array();
            $i = 1;
            if (!empty($resultadoList)) {
                foreach ($resultadoList as $key => $value) {
                    $nombreApellido = $value['Nombre_Cliente'] . ' ' . $value['Apellido_Cliente'];
                    $acciones = '<div class="list-icons"><a href="#" id="verOtServicioTecnico" value="' .
                        $value['ID_OTServicioTecnico'] . '" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon" type="button"><i class="icon-info22"></i></a><a href="#" id="editarOtServicioTecnico" value="' .
                        $value['ID_OTServicioTecnico'] . '" class="btn btn-warning btn-icon" type="button"><i class="icon-pencil7"></i></a><a href="#" id="eliminarOtServicioTecnico" value="' .
                        $value['ID_OTServicioTecnico'] . '"  class="btn btn-danger btn-icon" type="button"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></div>';
                    
                    $resultado['data'][] = array(
                        $i++,
                        $nombreApellido,
                        $value['Nombre_Documento'],
                        $value['NumeroDocumento_OTServicioTecnico'],
                        $value['Descripcion_OTServicioTecnico'],
                        $value['Fecha_OTServicioTecnico'],
                        $value['Total_OTServicioTecnico'],
                        $acciones
                    );
                }
            } else {
                $resultado['data'] = array();
            }
            
            echo json_encode($resultado);
            
            
        }
```